# Angular - Year Picker Only

Tags: angular8, angular-reactive-forms, ngb-datepicker

How to use reactive form and set form-control value (e.g.2018) in ngb-datepicker as only year picker?

I used below link code but can't set/selected value in year picker.

Please See this link : https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-year-datepicker-ng-bootstrap-8ag1xe